# Inner matrix must agree. MATLAB single-server queue

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to graph the equations below. It's the Kraemer and Lagenbach-Belz formula, if anyone is familiar with it. The parameters are 
    0 < t < 1
    0 < cA < 4
    0 < cS < 4

I think I'm just not multiplying the arrays right. Maybe I need to store Wq as an array? or put a for statement? I'm not very familiar with MATLAB. I also tried without the if statements with no luck. error with matrices.

```
t = 0:.1:1;
cA= 0:.1:4;
cS= 0:.1:4;


p = t;

if(cA <= 1)
    Wq = ((t*p)/(1-p))*((cA+cS)/2)*exp(-(2*(1-p))/(3*p))*((1-cA)^2/(cA+cS));
else
    Wq = ((t*p)/(1-p))*((cA+cS)/2)*exp((-(1-p))*((cA-1)/(cA+4*cS)));
end

plot(Wq,t)
```

Comment: Try replacing `/` with `./` and `*` with `.*` for elementwise operations.

Comment: You are using matrix multiplication. t*p = (11x1 vector)*(11*1 vector) ~= (11x1 vector).